# What is the netmask equivalent on the version of route for the Mac

Tags: mac, routing

In order to create some special routes for debugging I used the following command on my linux server:

```
sudo route add -net 10.78.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 gw 10.101.1.1
```

which works, and sets up the routes I need.  But when I run the same command on my Mac I get:

```
route: bad address: netmask
```

I'm guessing that the version of route that is included in OS X requires a different format but I'm at a loss to figure it out.

Comment: Manpages are your friend :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your Linux-style route command should translate to the following BSD-style command:

```
route add 10.78.0.0 10.101.1.1 -netmask 255.255.0.0
```

Or even shorter:

```
route add 10.78.0.0/16 10.101.1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I remember well, the Netmask to 10.x.x.x addresses is usualy 255.0.0.0. did you tried that?

Or did you divided your 10. range into multiple nets?